# Exactness for sequential unions of monomorphisms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Does the following [exactness property](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exactness+property) have a name?

Consider a category that has pullbacks, and colimits of countable sequences of monomorphisms.  Suppose given a diagram

[image: pair of countable unions]

such that each $A_n \to A_{n+1}$ is monic, the bottom row is a colimit, and all the squares

[image: partial square]

are pullbacks (hence each $B_n \to B_{n+1}$ is also monic).  Then the exactness property says that the top row is a colimit if and only if all the squares

[image: final square]

are pullbacks.

Comment: Yes - the category is called 'exhaustive'. See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exhaustive%20category ;-P

Comment: For everyone else, check the references at that nLab page.

Comment: @David: Very funny.

Comment: Also: according to the definition I put on the nLab, what I described in the above question is technically an $\omega$-exhaustive (or "countably exhaustive") category.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's answered in the comments.

Comment: @DavidWhite I think answering with a community wiki is probably the better answer, as I think of closing as saying that the question is not fit for the site (and this question is fit); I put the comment answer as a community wiki instead.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the relevant term seems to be [exhaustive](http://%20ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exhaustive%20category); the term was defined in response to this question.